# Sharepoint online chart using library data not list data

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, chart, graphical-indicators

Is it possible to generate a chart webpart that will show data from a sharepoint document library as opposed to a list.

I have over 2000 documents in a library and would like to generate a webpart chart that would show some type of summary of the content.   Eg. Total number of files by type.  I know that the quick chart feature can be pointed to lists but how can I get something similarly for my document library?

Comment: Or alternatively can a list be created to count details automatically from the library.  Eg show unique cakes in a volume of library (document types from a column named that) and then have a count column in the list which is a calculated field to count the instances of each document type and show the total number of records...... so a two column list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build custom chart report by google chart.

Get data by rest api.

My test demo in below thread.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bf8daadd-1ff0-4b19-ac5e-c2b46b4ea88c/error-with-dropdowns-filters-on-google-charts?forum=sharepointdevelopment